# Angular2, editable data table, ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ng2-bootstrap

I have a requirement to be able to display, sort, edit and add new rows to a table which gets/stores it's data in a database.

I have looked at using ag-grid for angular 2, and I am able to display & sort no problem. However, I can not find any documentation for adding a new row. Is ag-grid a good choice for adding/editing data? If so, how do you handle adding a new row?

Secondly, I have heard good things about primeNG but am already using ng2-bootstrap components. Is it a bad idea to use both?

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up using the primeNg dataTable component and it has worked well.

Answer (score 3):

Looking for table with multiple functionality with a minimum code  simply go fo `PrimeNg` , yes no problem if you are using ng2-bootstrap as well as primeng components side by side, also there are alot of functionalitys that are provided by primeng like

> Sorting, Searching, Templating, Filtering, Export, Editable and much more

for adding new row at run time simply add(push) new object into the array of rows.

Have a look here

- http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Answer (score 1):

right now, to add new row to ag-Grid, you need to call setRowData() (or bind new data to the row-data attribute).

adding and removing rows in ag-Grid is in the pipeline, will be included in a release later this year.

Comment: ag-Grid now allows ad find and removing rows, since v5.1